# How to use js.erb feature of rails in Rails 6 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

How to use js.erb feature of rails in Rails 6 version?

With rails 6 comes with webpacker, we need to add Jquery as custom option.
Is there any way to make js.erb working.

I have jquery working with below setting

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
}))

module.exports = environment
```

Even though js.erb is not working.

Comment: Might help

https://gorails.com/forum/jquery-doesn-t-work-in-js-erb-file

Answer (score 3):

In order to use jQuery in your JS.erb files you need to provide jQuery as a global.

Install jQuery with Yarn or NPM:

```
$ yarn add jquery
```

Make sure you have the webpack dev server running:

```
$ bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Require jQuery in your `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
global.jQuery, global.$ = require("jquery");
```

Comment: please check updates... I have jquery working in my application